# How to sum the list in template django?

Tags: python, django

I want to get the sum of the moneylog_set.price 
so i try to assign total_pay but the error occur

**view.py**

```
def all_moneybooks(request):
    current_user = request.user
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        current_user_moneybooks = current_user.owner.all()
        total_pay = 0
        book_total_pay_list = []
        for current_user_moneybook in current_user_moneybooks:
            moneylog_set = current_user_moneybook.moneylog_set.all()
            for moneylog in moneylog_set:
                total_pay += moneylog.price
                book_total_pay_list.append(
                    (moneylog.moneybook.id, moneylog.price))

                print(dir(moneylog_set))
                print(book_total_pay_list)

        return render(request, "home.html", context={"current_user": current_user, "all_moneybooks": all_moneybooks, "current_user_moneybooks": current_user_moneybooks, "total_pay": total_pay, "book_total_pay_list": book_total_pay_list})
    else:
        return render(request, "home.html", context={"current_user": current_user, "all_moneybooks": all_moneybooks})
```

**home.html**

```
 {% for current_user_moneybook in current_user_moneybooks %}
        <a href="{% url "moneybooks:detail" current_user_moneybook.pk %}"> 
            <div class="border-gray-400 border-t border-b border-l border-r">
                <div class="container flex mx-auto">
                    <div class="w-1/5 my-10">
                        <p class="text-center text-gray-900">{{current_user_moneybook.country}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-3/5 my-3">
                        <div class="inline-block align-middle text-gray-900 font-bold text-xl mb-2">{{current_user_moneybook.name}}</div>
                        <div class="text-gray-700 text-sm">{{current_user_moneybook.companion.all}}</div>
                        <div class="text-gray-900 text-sm">{{current_user_moneybook.start_date|date:"Y년 m월 d일"}} ~ {{current_user_moneybook.end_date|date:"Y년 m월 d일"}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-1/5 my-10">
                            <div class="text-center text-gray-900 text-gray-900 font-bold text-xl mb-2">
                                {{book_total_pay_list[current_user_moneybook.pk:2].sum()}}
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        {% endfor %}
```

> Could not parse the remainder: '[current_user_moneybook.pk:2]' from 'book_total_pay_list[current_user_moneybook.pk:2]'

is there any other method or more query way?
also, I guessenter code here .sum() method is not working. is there other method to sum this price list?

Comment: Why not write a custom filter for this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: i can't understand what you mean.